# Ajax get request returns 404 in Opencart, works locally

Tags: jquery, ajax, opencart

i've been messing about with Opencart and ran into the following issue, i'm trying to get the file `text.txt` with an ajax call inserted into the header of my page.

I had the following code locally, that is a local html file:

```
<div id="textGoesHere"></div>

<script>
var text =        
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url : "text.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                $("#textGoesHere").html(data);
                text = data;
                console.log(text);
            }
        });
console.log(text);
</script>
```

Wich works without any errors or issues, yet if I try the exact same code in my Opencart installation I get the following error:
`GET http://mysite.nl/text.txt 404 (Not Found)`

```
var text =     
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url : "text.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $("#notice").html(data);
            text = data;
            console.log(text);
            console.log(data);
        }    
    });
```

The div notice exists, my opencart ftp directory looks like this: 
[image]

Changing the url in the $.ajax call to `http://mysite.nl/text.txt` gives the same error also. Same goes with `index.php?route=text.txt`

Hoping anyone here can give me a good pointer where to look. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the contents of your htaccess? Might be a problem with the redirect rules, or - rare but possible - txt is not in the server filetypes list. Anyway this does not look like a javascript problem at all.

Comment: Heya @axel.michel seems the rare case was the truthy one. My htaccess didn't allow .txt files indeed. the issue is fixed now, thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you misspelled `text.txt` in your ftp folder, should be called `text.txt`, not `tekst.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunatly that was not the problem it seems, gives the same error but updated my question!